# Check condition and swap values in a Grouped dataframe

Tags: python

There is a way to swap the values of a grouped dataframe if it matchs the condition?

I have the following dataframe that I grouped by date and product and the value is the mean.

| date | product | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | cotton | 500.00 |
|  | coffee | 300.00 |
| 02/01/2023 | cotton | 400.00 |
|  | coffee | 600.00 |

I know that cotton is always more expensive than coffee. There is a way to check each date to swap the value of the products if it match the conditions?

My desired output is:

| date | product | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | cotton | 500.00 |
|  | coffee | 300.00 |
| 02/01/2023 | cotton | 600.00 |
|  | coffee | 400.00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a lambda function after you `groupby` the data by date and sort them by `value` column in the lambda function.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the original DataFrame
data = {
    'date': ['01/01/2023', '01/01/2023', '02/01/2023', '02/01/2023'],
    'product': ['cotton', 'coffee', 'cotton', 'coffee'],
    'value': [500.00, 300.00, 400.00, 600.00]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Group the DataFrame by 'date' and calculate the mean value
grouped_df = df.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('value')).reset_index(drop=True)

# Swap the values if the condition is met (cotton value > coffee value)
condition = grouped_df['product'] == 'cotton'
cotton_values = grouped_df.loc[condition, 'value']
coffee_values = grouped_df.loc[~condition, 'value']
grouped_df.loc[condition, 'value'] = coffee_values.values
grouped_df.loc[~condition, 'value'] = cotton_values.values

# Display the modified DataFrame
print(grouped_df)
```

The output;

```
         date product  value
0  01/01/2023  coffee  500.0
1  01/01/2023  cotton  300.0
2  02/01/2023  cotton  600.0
3  02/01/2023  coffee  400.0
```